# Connecting DataBase using PHP PDO in Xml to Fetch Data to Show in RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, pdo, rss

```
 <?php
// Please note that the file is saved as rss.php and the xml code is included in it. 

// Include necessary files
include_once '../inc/function.inc.php';
include_once '../inc/db.inc.php';

// Till here no problem

// Open a database connection
$db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// When i connect to database I get error.
// in Internet Explorer: This feed contains code error
//in Mozila: Its pops up a rss.php and asks me to open it and save to a specific location
/in Chrome: It displays all the code as it is in the Browser 

// Load all blog entries
$e = retrieveEntries($db, 'blog');

// Remove the fulldisp flag
array_pop($e);

// Perform basic data sanitization
$e = sanitizeData($e);

// Add a content type header to ensure proper execution
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');

// Output the XML declaration
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";



?>


<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
        <title>My Simple Blog</title>
        <link>http://localhost/simple_blog/</link>
        <description>This blog is awesome.</description>
        <language>en-us</language>

        <?php
        // Loop through the entries and generate RSS items
        foreach($e as $e):

        // Escape HTML to avoid errors
        $entry = htmlentities($e['entry']);

        // Build the full URL to the entry
        $url = 'http://localhost/simple_blog/blog/' . $e['url'];
        ?>

        <item>
        <title><?php echo $e['title']; ?></title>
        <description><?php echo $entry; ?></description>
        <link><?php echo $url; ?></link>
        </item>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    

</channel>
</rss>
```

I have explained in form of comments in the code what problems I am facing. Please let me know if I am connecting correctly.

Am I missing something with respect to code or Syntax using xml in php?

Comment: What is in `DB_INFO`? Also description of the problem should be contained in the text part of your question and not as comments of the code.

Comment: what those DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS) variable contain ?

Comment: are you sure its like `PDO('mysql:host=blabla;dbname=blabla', $user, $pass);` ?

Comment: `It displays all the code as it is in the Browser` **what code it displays?** one code example worth 1000 words. is it PHP code? Or desired RSS code? Or malformed RSS code? What does ConnecTing To DataBase To Do With All This?

Answer (score 0):

Just shot in the dark

> Please note that the file is saved as rss.php

Judging by the symptoms, either is is not saved as rss.php, or there is no PHP installed on the server.